# Initialization of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I declare an array on dimension n, where n is the max number of elements that the array can contain:

```
int array[] = new int [n];
```

I have an algorithm that fills this array with values from 0 to maxValue. For example:

```
   array[0] = 0;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 4;
    array[3] = 5;
```

Let n = 8, if I print the array with:

```
System.out.println("array " + Arrays.toString(array));
```

I will have this output:

0 1 4 5 0 0 0 0

If I want check if there is the value 0 in the array, how can I do excluding the values that are derived from the initialization of the array? Basically i want consider just  0 1 4 5  and not 0 1 4 5 0 0 0 0.

This can be explained because if I have an array without value 0 for example:

```
    array[0] = 3;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 4;
    array[3] = 5;
```

Every element in the array that is not assigned, it will be 0. So for n=8 i will have 3 1 4 5 0 0 0 0 and if I check if the value 0 is in the array i will receive a positive.

Comment: If there are no gaps, I'd use `ArrayList` instead of an array, and let it deal with managing the underlying capacity.

Comment: @NPE - Or, to avoid the boxing/unboxing overhead of an `ArrayList`, use a third-party primitive collections library like [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/) or [HPCC](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html). (See the [NIST JavaNumerics page](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/) for more libraries.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, basically - not based on just the array itself. There *is* no difference between a value which was explicitly set to 0 and one which just defaulted to 0.

You could change your array to be of type `Integer[]` - then you'd have `null` values for anything you haven't explicitly initialized. However, you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between those defaults and explicitly setting an array element to null...

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the array values to something "out of range" lets say -1. Then you'll be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter variable to track how many indexes you've assigned. You can then loop over your indexes using this counter to only check the initialized indexes. This is assuming that you're assigning values into the indexes incrementally.